# How to link to user profile in wiki

Tags: wiki, user, asseturlselector

I'm looking to add simple links to different users within a wiki article (i.e. "John defined the original request, which was then expanded on my Jane." where John and Jane linked to their profile views respectfully).

I don't see wiki code for this, and when I try to insert from Insert>From SharePoint>Asset Menu Selector, I can't find where user data is stored. What am I missing? Is there no easy way to do this without programming or searching for URL's manually?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've done this is in code, but it's always been dynamic when I needed to do this. Have you tried just copying the Url of their profiles and pasting it in an html anchor tag? That should work.

Comment: like < a href=" " > John < /a > minus the spaces

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm doing now, it just means I need to look them up in a separate tab. I'm just looking for a better option.

Comment: yeah, you can do it through code by basically recreating that same URL you're copy and pasting, but there isn't an OOTB way that I'm aware of. Even through code you either need the full name or login name of the user.